# How to embed double quotes in Twig interpolation?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, interpolation

I am trying to replace `sprintf(' href="%s%s"', ..., ...)` from a PHP file into its Twig alternative. I'd like to use Twig's interpolation feature but, the string expression has to be wrapped in double-quotes and *contains* embedded quotes surrounding the href attribute values.

Is there a way to do this? The docs seem fairly light weight in this regard.

`{{ " href="#{value1}#{value2)"" }}`

Comment: Escaping is not enough, because twig will do an html autoescaping on the resulting string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to include `"` you need to escape the character

```
{{ " href=\"#{value1}#{value2)\"" }}
```

**But it's not a good idea**

A better way is to include your value directly in the attribute like :

```
<a href="{{url}}">Some link</a>
```

And of course, you can use concatenation

```
<a href="{{value1~value2}}">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

**The best solutions is :**

```
href="{{value1}}{{value2}}"
```

Doing so, both value1 and value2 will safely be escaped regarding HTML special characters. And your double quotes will directly be outputed.

**Why your method is bad practice :**

What you want to do is (these two are equivalent) :

```
{{ " href=\"#{value1}#{value2}\"" }}
```

Or

```
{{ ' href="'~value1~value2~'"' }}
```

Doing it so, it will escape the href double quotes and integrate them in the concatenation.

But since the concatenation is in {{ ... }} twig will also escape every resulting double quotes with the HTML autoescape, they will be replaced with `&quot;`.

You could disable this html autoescaping so :

```
{{ 'href="'~value1~value2~'"' | raw}}
```

But then it is dangerous, because value1 and value2 won't be html escaped anymore, and you will be exposed to XSS injections.

Comment: _The best solution_ and then _Some bad practices_. What should people see first and use?